# What does this specific C++ code mean?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
Kuvio::Kuvio(Piste& paikka, string& nimi) : paikka(paikka), nimi(nimi) {}
```

Do not care about the words. I'd like to know is that a function definition, a function call or what? I'm not familiar with C++.

Comment: I suggest you pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), C++ is not easy to parse (for humans or compilers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a definition of the constructor of class `Kuvio` using an initialization list.

It's almost equivalent to:

```
Kuvio::Kuvio(Piste& paikka, string& nimi) 
{
   paikka = paikka; 
   nimi = nimi; 
}
```

, which is redundant. In general however, the difference is that the members are not initialized two times, as it would happen with my snippet of code, but only once in the initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

Function definition, constructor of class `Kuvio`.

Comment: What is the colon part of it? `: paikka(paikka), nimi(nimi)`?

Comment: That's the initializer list. It states that the initial values of the two class members are the two arguments to the ctor.

Answer (score 2):

It's defining the constructor of class Kuvio. The part between `:` and `{}` is an initializer list - it takes paikka and nimi member variables and initializes them with the values of paikka and nimi parameters.